# Subscribe a user to a topic in Firebase when uid has changed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

My question is:
When I subscribe a user to a chat, let's say that the chat has an id of "xDs50Yss70", the user remains subscribed while the user's Firebase uid has not changed.
However, when the Firebase uid of the user changes, for instance when the user has deleted the app and downloaded it again, the user is no longer subscribed to the chat, and other subscriptions that he/she might have.

I use this function to subscribe a user to a chat when the chat is firstly created

```js
function subscribeUserToATopic(registrationTokens, chatId) {
    return admin.messaging().subscribeToTopic(registrationTokens, chatId)
}
```

As we can see we use the registration token to subscribe the user to the `chatId`, I use the registration token gotten from this code (in the client side):

```
@Override
public void onNewToken(String newToken) {
    super.onNewToken(newToken);

    // Send the new token to Firestore
    sendTokenToDatabase(newToken);
}
```

I send the token to Firestore database using the `sendTokenToDatabase()`, however when the user deletes the app and reinstall it, the token changes... And I no longer can send push notification using this code, since the user's token changed :

```
admin.messaging().sendToTopic(chatId, payload, options).then(() => {
        console.log(`Push notification sent to the user(s) subscribed to the ${chatId}`)
    }).
```

Comment: What type of authentication do you use? For email/password and authentication through social providers, the Firebase UID will remain the same even after the user reinstalls the app.

Comment: I'm using Google and Facebook authentication only.

Comment: So that means a user's UID is the same, even when they uninstall/reinstall the app, sign in from a web site, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The token you're referring to is the [device registration token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register). It can change in the following events:

- The app deletes Instance ID
- The app is restored on a new device
- The user uninstalls/reinstalls the app
- The user clears app data

In each of these cases you need to get hold of the new registration token, and subscribe it to the topics you care about. Hopefully, all the above events are rare for any given user, so you don't have to do that too often.

Now it seems you represent a chat (I assume this is like a specific conversation or a chatroom in your app), with a topic. So your topics can vary among users. This means you have to also keep track of the topics for each user independently. Store the list of chats/topics for each user, keyed by their unique UIDs in the database. UIDs are constant throughout, so you don't have to worry about them changing over time.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two possible solutions. They both invlove setting the subscription again when the **onNewToken** method is invoked, or for previous versions of FCM the **onTokenRefresh** method.

So what you need to do is get the list of topics the user was subscribed to, and **subscribeToTopic** again for each topic. If you have them on your server you can get them from there or you can have them stored locally on the user's device (ie SharedPreferences, database, etc) retrieve them and set them again.

Answer (score 1):

When a user first logs into Firebase Authentication using email+password, or one of the social providers (such as Facebook, Google, etc), a unique UID is determined for their account. For there on this UID stays the same after that until you delete their account. That means that if a user uninstalls and reinstalls the app, they'll get the same UID when they log in.

Comment: ohh ok... So the Firebase token is independent on the user's uid...  However how can I re-subscribe the user to the previous topics when the token has changed. Since to my knowledge the token changes because of multiple reasons

Comment: It is incredibly hard to follow what you're actually doing right now. I suggest that you update your question with a minimal piece of code that reproduces what you are asking about. For example, show how you sign in and subscribe.

Answer (score 1):

This is an extension to Frank's answer, and based on your updated question with Token.

A **Firebase ID tokens** expire only when one of the following occurs:

1. The user is deleted
2. The user is disabled
3. A major account change is detected for the user. This includes events like password or email address updates.

Which is not your case, so, at this point, what you need to do is to **REVOKE refresh tokens**.

> **Revoke refresh tokens**
>
> You might revoke a user's existing refresh token
>   when a **user reports a lost or stolen device**. Similarly, if you
>   discover a general vulnerability or suspect a wide-scale leak of
>   active tokens, you can use the listUsers API to look up all users and
>   revoke their tokens for the specified project.
>
> Password resets also revoke a user's existing tokens; however, the
>   Firebase Authentication backend handles the revocation automatically
>   in that case. On revocation, the user is signed out and prompted to
>   reauthenticate.

For the full details on implementation and documentation you get it in the doc [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions). (Lengthy)